# What is the correct way to document PHP constants (define) with phpDocumentor

Tags: php, constants, phpdoc

How must we document (with [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)) constants defined with [define()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) in PHP?

I found nothing in the docs, but found the following example (which I don't see it's use) in the sample2.php:

```
/**#@+
 * Constants
 */
/**
 * first constant
 */
define('testing', 6);
/**
 * second constant
 */
define('anotherconstant', strlen('hello'));
```

Anyone can tell me what's the best way to document constants in PHP with phpDocumentor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define statements are in general only commented with a descriptive text, so that's basically how you comment it.

To read more about the DocBlock template tag, `/**#@+`, check out [the manual page](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.docblocktemplate).

Comment: No particular tag is necessary.  The "template tag" that appears at the top of your example is only there as a shortcut that *adds* your "Constants" description piece into each of your individual descriptions ("first constant", "second constant").  The use of that template tag is only needed if you indeed want to put some common text into multiple separate descriptions.

Comment: All links are dead

Answer (score 1):

You have at phpDoc.org [the elements that can be documented](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#documenting.elements).

You also have [an example of documenting a define()](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.starting) (the second piece of code and surrounding paragraphs).

Comment: That example is actually trying to demonstrate that having the "define" statement incorrectly sandwiched between function foo() and the function's docblock will cause the docblock to be incorrectly associated with the defined constant instead of the function.  I don't really see a useful example in the tutorial to show documenting a constant, so I found one in one of phpDocumentor's files itself... look at the bottom of the page here (http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/__filesource/fsource_phpDocumentor_Parsers_phpDocumentorConvertersXMLDocBookpeardoc2Tokenizer.php.html).

Comment: All links are dead

Comment: The project changed the location of the documentation. New location: https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest (Sorry, I can't find the sections I posted)

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
*@const
*/
const testing=6;
const anotherconstant=strlen('hello');
```

Try this you will See it As Constant