# What is the correct way to write PHPDocs for constants?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have this code:

```
/**
 * Days to parse
 * @var int
 */
const DAYS_TO_PARSE = 10;
...
```

I don't think that using `@var` is correct for a constant and I don't see any `@constant` PHPDoc tag. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: As far as `define` is concerned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192751/what-is-the-correct-way-to-document-php-constants-define-with-phpdocumentor

Comment: I saw that one, define is for standalone constants, I am looking for a class constant

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpDoc class constants documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892063/phpdoc-class-constants-documentation)

Comment: @Elzo `const FOO = 1;` works outside class context as well.

Comment: this guy is using @access private http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phpdoc.html, but I am not aware of the fact that you can restrict visibility for constants

Comment: @Elzo Valugi: There are no private class constants in PHP and I doubt this hardly makes sense to have them. Anyway, that guy most certainly refers to *visibility by documentation* as it was common for public class functions as well in times when visibility was not available in PHP. It's a lint tool, that just is non-conservative to allow such.

Comment: To add to Yogarine's answer, apparently just using a plain docblock works well with Doxygen. If you include the @var part, the resulting documentation won't include the description you keyed in.

Answer (score -22, accepted):

To get them into phpDoc, use:

```
@const THING
```

Usual construct:

```
@const[ant] label [description]
```

Comment: isn't the a difference between class constants and global constants initiated by define()? I guess @const is for notating the latter.

Comment: It's the former. I just documented a class constant and my generated phpdocs correctly contain the description. And as of April 2017 the English docs still don't have `@const`!

Comment: `@const` is not valid and does not exist in PHPDocumentor. Use `@var`.

Comment: It was valid at time of writing. Thanks.

Comment: Though Brian is correct that there seems to be [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892174/904344) that at the time of writing, there was documentation on using a `@const[ant]` doc-style tag (PHP Doc 1.0 beta), I don't see why you wouldn't update an answer that is now incorrect after 11 years.

Answer (score 170):

[The PHP-FIG suggests using `@var` for constants.](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md)

> 7.22. `@var`
>
> You may use the `@var` tag to document the "Type" of the following
>   "Structural Elements":
>
> - Constants, both class and global scope
> - Properties
> - Variables, both global and local scope
>
> Syntax
>
> `@var ["Type"] [element_name] [<description>]`

Comment: So what is essentially is short for "variable" we use for documenting something that is "constant"?

Comment: as of 2017 using `@const` will correctly output my description but `@var` will not output anything for a class constant.

Comment: This is outdated. The current version of the PSR-5 draft no longer specifically mentions this. I maintain that constants don't need a specific type hint because their type is immutable and can always be deduced:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50945077/752110

Comment: @Yogarine constants may not need a type-hint, but it may be desirable to document what the constant is used for

Comment: @BradKent Of course. In that case it suffices to just add a docblock without any annotations.

Comment: This is insufficient if you want to define constants that Traits use from their placement and you can't define the constant on the Trait itself since then it has to be the same on the using class...

Answer (score 131):

`@const` is **not** the right answer.

- It's not part of the legacy phpDocumentor docs: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/
- It's not part of the current phpDocumentor docs: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html
- It's not listed in the list of tags on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#Tags
- It's not listed in the PHP-FIG draft PSR: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#7-tags

The only "official" place it's listed is phpdoc.de, but the spec there only ever made it to 1.0beta, and the site also includes tags like `@brother` and `@sister`, which I've never seen used before, so the overall trust in that site is somewhat diminished ;-) The de facto 
standard has always been phpDoc.org.

In short, even if some unofficial standard does mention it, if the documentation generators don't support it, then it's not worth using.

`@var` is correct <del>for now, and once the PSR (last link in the above list) is out of draft, and is the basis for which phpDocumentor, Doxygen, APIGen and others are understanding PHPDoc, then `@type` would be correct which is the successor to `@var`</del>.

Comment: Eventually, [`@type` was dropped in favor of `@var`](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/commit/61c695c43d1b2c713acbfb3302f284c518421bc5).

Comment: In fact it doesn't seem to matter at all for IDEs, PHPStorm for example always takes the actual code value to find out the type (as it must have a value assigned).

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to annotate the type of constants, since the type is always:

- either a scalar or an array
- known at declaration time
- immutable

`@const` is also not part of the PHPDoc standard. PHP-FIG suggests `@var` but this is not backed by PHPDoc and doesn't add any information you can't already deduce from the declaration itself.

Therefore, for the sake of readability I recommend just using a plain PHPDoc docblock to document your constants:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * This is a constant.
     */
    const BAR = 'bar';
}
```

It will describe the constant when you generate PHPDocs yet keeps the comments clean and readable.

Answer (score 4):

I use Netbeans. It will parse phpDoc for global and class constants when this format is used:

```
/** @const Global constant description */
define('MY_CONST', 10);

class MyClass
{
    /** @const Class constant description */
    const MY_CONST = 10;
}
```

Comment: Can't you leave the `@const` out for the class constants in Netbeans?

Comment: I just tested in Netbeans 8, and was able to omit `@const` for the global and class constant declarations.

Comment: In my case, i added "/** Class constant description */" and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The following [proposition](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#722-var) respects [the official documentation syntax](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html#syntax):

```php
class Foo
{
    const
        /**
         * @var string Should contain a description
         */
        MY_CONST1 = "1",
        /**
         * @var string Should contain a description
         */
        MY_CONST2 = "2";

}
```