# phpdoc not parsing constant description

Tags: php, phpdoc

I've been trying to document my configuration file, following the phpdocumentor documention I started with a simplified config file which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Configuration / Settings file
 * 
 * @package site
 * @copyright 2013
 * @author Nick
 * 
 */
/**
 * Switch development mode on/off
 */
define('DEV_MODE',true);
```

The above constant pulls through into the documentation, however all it shows is the constant name (`DEV_MODE`), not any description.

Then I found [this other question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706051/phpdoc-for-constants), which suggests adding `@const` to define the constant:

```
/**
 * Configuration / Settings file
 * 
 * @package site
 * @copyright 2013
 * @author Nick
 * 
 */
/**
 * Switch development mode on/off
 * @const DEV_MODE
 */
define('DEV_MODE',true);
```

But this still hasn't done anything different.

Not sure if it matters or not, but I'm using the phar file to run phpDoc.

Can anyone see something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I actually don't see anything wrong in your original code above.  It may be a bug with the phpdoc2 phar, so I suggest opening a github issue on it.

Comment: @ashnazg thanks, I will do that shortly. Just assumed it was me doing something wrong, as I haven't used phpdoc much before.